# How can I use resultMap with type of HashMap to select list of HashMap with MyBatis?

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

My tables are like this:

```sql
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."agri_pest_control";
    CREATE TABLE "public"."agri_pest_control" (
      "pest_type" varchar(10) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" DEFAULT ''::character varying,
      "pest_status" bit(3) DEFAULT '000'::"bit",
      "crop_type" varchar(20) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
      "id" int8 NOT NULL,
      "comments" varchar(255) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
      "land_id" int8,
      "test_time" timestamp(6)
    )

    ALTER TABLE "public"."agri_pest_control" ADD CONSTRAINT "agri_pest_control_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id");

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."agri_land";
    CREATE TABLE "public"."agri_land" (
      "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('agri_land_id_seq'::regclass),
      "geom" "public"."geometry",
      "shape_area" float8,
      "county_id" int2
    )
    ;

    ALTER TABLE "public"."agri_land" ADD CONSTRAINT "agri_land_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id");
```

Here is my Mapper function:

```java
    List<Map<String, Object>> selectStatistics(
            @Param("landId") Long landId,
            @Param("pestStatus")byte[] pestStatus,
            @Param("pestType") String pestType,
            @Param("cropType") String cropType,
            @Param("testStartTime") LocalDateTime localDateTime,
            @Param("testEndTime") LocalDateTime localDateTime1,
            @Param("statisticsFirstObject") String statisticsFirstObject,
            @Param("statisticsSecondObject") String statisticsSecondObject
            );
```

And I have a Mapper.xml file like this:

```xml
    <resultMap id="statisticsMap" type="java.util.HashMap">
            <id property="id" column="row_num"></id>
            <result column = "pest_status" property = "pest_status" typeHandler="cn.iocoder.yudao.module.agri.utils.BitByteaTypeHandler"/>
    </resultMap>
    <select id="selectStatistics" resultMap="statisticsMap">
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over
        ( ORDER BY sl.area ) as row_num, * from
        (SELECT
            ${statisticsFirstObject} as ${statisticsFirstObject},
            ${statisticsSecondObject} as ${statisticsSecondObject},
            count(whl.id) count,
            sum(whl.poly_area) area
        FROM
            agri_pest_control AS pc
        JOIN agri_land whl ON whl.ID = pc.land_id
        <where>
            1=1
            <if test="pestStatus != null and pestStatus.length!=0">
                AND pest_status = #{pestStatus,typeHandler=cn.iocoder.yudao.module.agri.utils.BitByteaTypeHandler}
            </if>
            <if test="cropType != null and cropType !=''">
                AND crop_type = #{cropType}
            </if>
            <if test="testStartTime != null and testEndTime != null">
                AND test_time between #{testStartTime} and #{testEndTime}
            </if>
            <if test="pestType != null and pestType!= ''">
                AND pest_type = #{pestType}
            </if>
            <if test="landId != null and landId != ''">
                AND land_id = #{landId}
            </if>
            AND pc.deleted = 0
            AND whl.deleted = 0
        </where>
            GROUP BY
            ${statisticsFirstObject} ,
            ${statisticsSecondObject}) sl
    </select>
```

Basically, I am trying to write a universal method to query the statistics of data based on two table field variables. However, the table field pest_status is a bit(3) which means [I need to configure typeHandler for this field.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76234163/how-do-i-insert-a-record-with-mybatis-while-column-type-is-postgresql-bitn-and) So I come up with the idea to use resultMap to configure typeHandler for the possibly queried field pest_status. Besides, as I want to reorganize the result to better suit json later, I choose HashMap to retrieve the value by its field name. Here is my reorganize function:

```java
    public static Map<String, Map<String, Object>> reorganize(String statisticsType, String statisticsFirstObject, String statisticsSecondObject, List<Map<String, Object>> StatisticsResultMapList){
        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> dict = new HashMap<>();
        List<Object> distinctFirstObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Object> distinctSecondObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (statisticsType!=null && !statisticsType.equals("")){
            for(Map<String, Object> statisticsResultMap:StatisticsResultMapList) {
                if(statisticsFirstObject != null && statisticsSecondObject != null){
                    if (!distinctFirstObjectList.contains(statisticsResultMap.get(statisticsFirstObject))){
                        distinctFirstObjectList.add(statisticsResultMap.get(statisticsFirstObject));
                    }
                    if (!distinctSecondObjectList.contains(statisticsResultMap.get(statisticsSecondObject))){
                        distinctSecondObjectList.add(statisticsResultMap.get(statisticsSecondObject));
                    }
                }
            }
            for(Object firstObject:distinctFirstObjectList){
                Map<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<>();
                for(Object secondObject:distinctSecondObjectList){
                    for(Map<String, Object> statisticsResultMap:StatisticsResultMapList){
                        if(statisticsResultMap.get(statisticsSecondObject).equals(secondObject) && statisticsResultMap.get(statisticsFirstObject).equals(firstObject)){
                            temp.put(secondObject.toString(), statisticsResultMap.get(statisticsType));
                        }
                    }
                    dict.put(firstObject.toString(), temp);
                }
            }
        }
        else
            throw exception(STATISTICS_TYPE_NOT_EXISTS);
        return dict;
    }
```

So I am expecting a list of map as the SQL result. When performing the following SQL content in navicat, the result is what I expected, but after some experiment, MyBatis actually returned me with a squeezed result:

Expected:

| row_num | county_id | pest_status | count | area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 132 | 1631432.957 |
| 2 | 1 | 000 | 144 | 1795440.317 |
| 3 | 1 | 011 | 137 | 1796610.9408 |
| 4 | 1 | 001 | 141 | 1824607.972 |
| 5 | 1 | 010 | 135 | 2280791.764 |
| 6 | 3 | 011 | 111 | 1852187.661 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Actual result:

| id | county_id | pest_status | count | area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | county_id | [48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48] | 9999 | 2.8841...E8 |

So how can I get a list of map results without hindering the typeHandler I needed in the resultMap?

Environment:

- PostgreSQL: 12.0
- Driver version: 42.3.8
- Java: 1.8.0_351
- MyBatis: 3.5.10
- MyBatis spring: 2.0.7
- MyBatis-plus: 3.5.3.1

Comment: You cannot use placeholder `#{}` for table/column names. You need to use `${}` instead. See the [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-). Be sure not to use untrusted values in `${}`. A general advice: enable TRACE level logging which shows you the parameterized statement, parameters and results.

Comment: Ah, my bad, you are surely right.

Comment: Amazingly, after I change the placeholder as you said, everything works fine now. Oh my lord, thank you my hero.  Though I still haven't figured out the way to configure trace level logging, I have managed to configure a debug level logging for my mapper, that is a really useful technique indeed.

Comment: Glad to know it worked!  The way to configure log level depends on the logging library you are using. There are a few examples in the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html). If you are using Spring Boot, it can be configured in `application.properties`.